# Is it the same when it says to write an equation of plane that contains two points and is determined by two points?

Tags: plane-geometry

All those plane equations are confusing me so much 
Is it the same when it says to write an equation of plane that contains two points and, is determined by two points ? (I am assuming that a vector is given aswell , because I think its not possible to write equation of plane if just 2 points are given )

Comment: two points is not enough to define a plane, there should be something else given, i.e. a line or another point

Comment: It might be a pencil of planes through a line.

Comment: What vector?  Normal vector to the plane or a vector lying on the plane?

Comment: what about a vector lying on the plane ?

Comment: is it the same if it says for example a plane is determined by 3 points and a plane contains 3 points ? (do you write the equation in the same way )?

Comment: If there is no context that says otherwise, then you are correct, the phrase "the plane determined by the 3 points $A, B, C$" will mean "the plane passing through the 3 points $A, B, C$". However, in certain contexts the author may be referring to other means of defining planes. In that case "determined by" means whatever method the author is currently talking about.